Jenkins EC2 plugin and tools
I have a jenkins which build a java project with EC2 plugin. But I have an issue with tools. I have an assumption which seems wrong... Is the tools like git / maven / credentials is handled by the agent and then installed in the instanciated node "on the fly" or I have to build an AMI with everything ?
If I have to do it with git / java I'm not surprised but for ssh credentials for git for example it's strange...
Did I miss something ?
